# Recording audio and removing noises

Tags: ios, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'm using AVAudioRecorder to make a record. Now I want to resume my existing record (add new record to an existing one), if user needs. I've found Extended Audio File Services. As I see, I need to:
1) create extended audio file
2) translate it into buffer
3) create extended file from multiple buffers
4) write it on disk
Is there any easier way to record in existing file?
Also I want to record only human's voice (without any other noises). iPhone 4 has 2 mics and possibly 1 mic from headset/headphones. Is there any standard API to make it?
Thanks.

Comment: have you found anything on removing noise from recording. I am working on this type of project. Any help will be appreciated.